# Backup Software Copy Data From 1x3TB to 3x1TB

Tags: backup

Im looking for a backup software (Windows 7 64-bit), with one particular need in mind.

I have a 3TB drive I want to be able to backup across 3 x 1TB drives.

I DO NOT want to RAID/Stripe the 1 TB drives to make a 3TB drive.

Comment: Do you mean a single copy/snapshot that can be updated or versioned/incremental backups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a feature in your backup software called drive spanning. One piece of software that does this is called Acron​is: True Image.

The vast majority of workstation backup software is designed to work with some removable drive or even more commonly a web repo that it uploads to (carbonite, mozy...) so updateable drive spanis a rather obscure feature in (non-enterprise) workstation backup software (hence the terrible quality of the website).

Answer (score -2):

Try sorting your files into 3 (or more) folders and use a back up program such as robo-copy to copy whatever folders you specify to your desired drive.

Comment: I would barely consider blindly copying files backup... and what if you have a file that is larger then any one of the drives. What if you accidentally put to many files in one of the folders. To much is left up to the user. And further more what about locked files and incremental backup, your solution leaves no way to deal with either.